# Reverse engineering a database with tables having no primary keys using Doctrine/Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Am trying to reverse engineer a database using Doctrine this way:

```
php app/console  doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/Acme/TxBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

or this way too (got the same issue):

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import TxBundle
```

But i allways get the below error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getColumns() on a non-object in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DatabaseDriver.php on line 134
Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumns() on a non-object in /var/www/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DatabaseDriver.php on line 134
```

It appears that i have some tables with no primary keys, i need to know if it is possible to make Doctrine work with these tables without altering the table structure to add the needed PKs ?

Comment: its been viewed 600 times yet no definitive answer to such common problems.